# Good HTTP Monitoring tools

Tags: http, telnet

I look for HTTP to work with a Linux system server monitor tool every protocol. 
I know, and will not there be it in whom or a freeware?

When, for example, I dump 80/tcp with a packet monitor to be concrete

```
 # tethereal -i ppp0 port 80 -x
Capturing on ppp0

1244206390.030474 219.111.xx.xx -> 74.125.xx.xx HTTP GET /search?output=js&num=0&dt=1244206414703&client=pub-3031568651010206&q=Cagliari%20Flight&ad=n3&ie=utf8&oe=utf8&channel=0091594208&adtest=off HTTP/1.1

0000  00 04 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00   ................
0010  45 00 01 e5 ee 82 40 00 40 06 d2 b5 db 6f 02 5b   E.....@.@....o.[
0020  4a 7d 4f 93 d4 29 00 50 3e df 4c 63 4b 6b 42 e0   J}O..).P>.LcKkB
```

Such output is provided, but there is too much unnecessary information such as an SYN packet or a header. 
What I want

1. The IP address of the client and
   sending out character string（Get;
   the contents of the POST）
2. Among the
   output character string of the
   server only as for the HTML
   (Content-Type:)  I am what is
   chisel) of a thing of text/html.

I can set a filter and am the best if only information wanting can accumulate in the log.

Comment: very similar  question I asked few hours ago, Take a look at
http://serverfault.com/questions/21926/network-monitoring-tool-for-freebsd

Comment: Please, please, please don't use Ethereal/Tethereal. It's coming up up on four years since we changed the name to Wireshark. A lot of serious bugs have been fixed and major improvements have been made in that time.

Answer (score 3):

[tcpflow](http://www.circlemud.org/~jelson/software/tcpflow/) A TCP Flow Recorder - is really a great tool to debug http
the filter syntax is the same as for tcpdump no need to learn another
syntax :)

Example curl of google.com:

```
$ tcpflow -c port 80 and host 74.125.43.103


010.190.001.182.55535-074.125.043.103.00080: GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.18.2 (i486-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.18.2 OpenSSL/0.9.8g zlib/1.2.3.3 libidn/1.10
Host: 74.125.43.103
Accept: */*


074.125.043.103.00080-010.190.001.182.55535: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Date: Mon, 08 Jun 2009 06:28:04 GMT
Expires: -1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Server: gws
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

[....]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the recording w/ tcpdump and later get the stuff you only need via wireshark

- http://www.wireshark.org
- http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html/#AppToolstcpdump